# MOSFET heat calculation question

Tags: mosfet, thermal, power-dissipation

I am using the FQP30N06L MOSFET: http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FQ/FQP30N06L.pdf.

As far as I understand the data sheet, if I connect 5V to the gate and run 2A through drain to source then with a \$R_{ds}\$ of \$0.035\$ I should get \$0.14 W\$.

\$I * I * R = P\$

\$2 * 2 * 0.035 = 0.14\$

So, with a R-theta junction-ambient of \$62.5 °C/W\$ that gives me \$8.75°C\$, or \$47.75 F\$.

So, if the ambient temperature is \$70 F\$ then that would make the junction \$117.75 F\$.

The data sheet says the max junction temperature is \$175 °C\$, so that should be fine, right? It will be hot, but should work OK.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: I'd suggest sticking to Celsius all the way through, and converting to Farenheit only at the end for comparison to your more familiar units of measure. Either that, or list all numbers in both sets of units. Jumping back and forth in the middle is bound to lead to errors.

For example, your conversion from C to F is off. A temperature of 8.75C does convert to a temperature of 47.75F. But a temperature DIFFERENCE of 8.75C only converts to a temperature difference of 14.85F. Try converting 100C and 108.75C to Farenheit to see why this is true.

Answer (score 6):

Your analysis oversimplifies a few things, but works out more or less correctly in the end. Just for general edification, I'll point out a couple things.

First, Rds isn't a fixed number, it varies with Vgs, temperature, and current. Figure 1 of the datasheet shows Vds vs. Ids for various values of Vgs. The reciprocal of the slope of this curve at a given current value is Rds.

For Vgs of 5V, the graph doesn't show anything for Ids = 2A, but we can extrapolate. Picking two points on the Vgs = 5V curve, we get a slope of 30 amps per volt, or (phrasing another way) an effective Rds of 33 mOhm.

Note that this assumes a junction temperature of 25C. From figure 2, we can see that at low currents, a hotter junction actually results in an even lower voltage for a given current, translating to a lower Rds. If you were running in a sub-zero ambient (say, equipment that lived outdoors in February in Moose Jaw), your Rds would be higher. But let's assume you're indoors in standard room temperatures.

So two amps RMS through 33 mOhm dissipates 132 mW of power, P = I^2 * R. .132W x 62.5 K/W gives a junction rise above ambient of 8.25K, or 14.85F. (1K = 1.8F) You might notice it get a little warmer to the touch, but that's it.

Max operating junction temperature is listed as 175C, so as long as your ambient is below 166.75C, you'll be fine thermally. If your ambient is higher than that, you're doing something either wrong or awesome.

Comment: +1 for "*either wrong or awesome*".

Comment: I got about 95% of what you said. Where you say there is a 30 amp per volt in figure 1, I am having a hard time seeing that. Along the bottom it looks like it goes from -100v to 0v to + 100v to me. Along the left side it looks like it goes from 0v to 10v to 100v. So is the left side saying that for a given negative voltage i would get a certain current? Otherwise i follow you. Thanks.

Comment: "you'll be fine thermally" is incorrect. Since when is running at a bit below Max Operating Temperature OK? Unless he wants the device to destroy itself quickly, he should remain in the recommended operating temperature region.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky, I'm afraid there's a misunderstanding somewhere. For any reasonable ambient, this FET will be well within its recommended temperature rating. My comment about running at 166C was a joke. Unless, of course, he's actually running in ambients that high...

Comment: @user1970899, that figure is on a logarithmic scale. It goes from 10^-1 (.1) to 10^0 (1) to 10^1 (10) volts on the horizontal axis, and from 10^0 (1) to 10^1 (10) to 10^2 (100) amps on the vertical axis. Does that help?

Comment: @Remiel: Sorry if I misunderstood. It seemed as if you said it was fine at that temp, when of course it isn't unless he knows it isn't and still decides to go with it for whatever reason.

Comment: Aha! Ok, that makes sense. I just had a duh! moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your math is correct and the MOSFET will run lukewarm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will be fine, and will not get hot.

The calculation is for temperature rise above ambient, so assuming e.g. a typical 25°C, it will only reach 33.75°C.

One thing though - though it makes little difference in this case, always design for worst case, which for the Rds is 0.45Ω, so you get 2^2 * 0.045Ω = 0.18W, so your temp rise could be up to 11.25°C. Note the value is for 16A Id, so you can expect a lower Rds at a lower Id according to figure 3 in the datasheet (Rds varies with various factors, so take note of the graphs).

This makes your calculations very conservative, but it's a good habit to get into.